# Socket.io on port 80

Tags: node.js, socket.io, port

I've made a node application which listens on port 80, my application works fine on localhost, but when I run it on my VPS, I get a different log and a different result ( websockets just don't work )

A comparison between localhost's log and VPS' log:

[Node's log on localhost](http://paste2.org/1ZWxZyEw)

[Node's log on VPS](http://paste2.org/61XkDBOE)

As you see, in VPS, xhr is used instead of websocket after it says "info: transport end (socket end)"

I don't use any web server on my VPS and I ran my application as root.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a web server in front of your node app on your VPS? If so, make sure it is new enough and properly configured to do websockets. For instance, on modern Ubuntu the stock nginx is not new enough yet to support web sockets, so you have to install a separate package to get websocket support.

2nd guess: is there a proxy server between your browser and your VPS?

Comment: No, I'm not using any web server, node does it all. will add more info to question, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you run it as the super user on the VPS?  Normal users are typically blocked from opening ports below 1024.

Comment: Yes, I ran it with root, node works fine, I can open up my webpage using my IP, it's on port 80, but the websockets do not work :<. thank for answer though

Answer (score 0):

Our server hosted on VPS, using port 80. The io connection fired through cellular data and through WIFI fine, but in some wifi networks it didn't.

So we had used different port, then it works.